# Flex DataBinding Drilling Down Through Arrays

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

The help page on the BindUtils.bindProperty function:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html

Has this to say:

"For example, to bind the property host.a.b.c, call the method as: bindProperty(host, ["a","b","c"], ...)."

But what if I need to bind to host.a.b[2].c?  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, flex lets me do this:
bindProperty(host, ["a","b","2","c"], ...);

Hazzah!

Answer (score 0):

There are often binding issues when you drill down into objects, at least under most normal binding sitautions.

Not sure if this is what you're after, but:

```
[Bindable] public var myObject = a.b[2];
```

And later in your code:

```
<myComp myValue="{myObject.c}" />
```

However, I would consider it highly unusual to bind to a specific element of an array.  If you could expand on what you're trying to do; maybe we can point you in a different direction.